# Android Studio Writing Test Scripts

Tags: android, unit-testing

I have moved from the implementation stage of my application to the testing phase. I am trying to write some unit tests but struggling with the concept. I have been able to set up and run the sample unit test in android studio, which passed.

It is a simple test that the result of 2+2 is equal to 4. This I understand, the issue is how do I write a unit test to test a more complex method of my application?

Take for example the method below which is used to register a user to a database using JSON. Obviously this method isnt as easy as 2+2, so how would one write a unit test for this?

I am also having issues with a simple test case that checks if an email is valid or not, the error I am getting is `cannot resolve method 'is(boolean)'`

**valid email test**

```
public class UnitTest {

@Test
public void validEmailTest() throws  Exception {
    assertThat(RegisterActivity.isValidEmail("rory@gmail.com"), is(true));
}
}
```

**Unit test Class**

```
import com.example.test.Activities.RegisterActivity;
import org.junit.Test;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;

public class UnitTest {


@Test
public void addition_isCorrect() throws Exception {
    assertEquals(4, 2 + 2);
}

@Test
public void validEmailTest() throws  Exception {
    assertThat(RegisterActivity.isValidEmail("rory@gmail.com"), is(true));
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Getting Started with Testing](http://developer.android.com/training/testing/start/index.html).

You should pay special attention to **Instrumented tests**, which are tests that run on an Android device or emulator and thus they have access to internal information of the application under test. Instrumented tests can be used for unit, user interface (UI), or app component integration testing.

You can find examples at https://github.com/googlesamples/android-testing

Comment: I had a look there already but still unsure as to how to apply the example to my code

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, i have had alook and I am a little clearer on what needs to be done, I updated the question with an error I cant seem to get rid of for a simple test

Comment: use `assertTrue()`